# Adding an additional command to git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

If I understand correctly, whenever I perform `git flow feature finish {my_feature}`, it is equivalent as if I were manually running the following 3 shell commands:

`git checkout develop`
`git merge --no-ff feature/{my_feature}`
`git branch -d feature/{my_feature}`

Is there any way I could specify an additional custom command that should be run, when I use the `git flow` command?

I know that if I want to add new commands exactly before or after the 3 commands that the `git flow` command runs, I could write a separate shell script. But what if I would like to add an additional command between the first two of these commands? Or what if I would like to eliminate the third delete branch command from this git flow operation? Is there any way I can do this, without writing custom shell scripts, and replicating what git flow does?